# GET operation status via API not CMD

Tags: google-cloud-vision

In Google [Cloud vision API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/operation-status) for the product search, the method for getting operation status is listed as CMD but there is no C# code example for it in order to check any long-running operation status.

I tried calling this method in postman but it didn't work as I cannot add the service account credentials

```
GET https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/locations/location-id/operations/operation-id
```

Would appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It turns out there are two solutions:**

1. Using Google Cloud Vision REST APIKEY as a query parameter for (you will have to generate your own API key from the cloud console credentials)

> ```
> GET https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/locations/location_id/operations/operation_id?key=value
> ```

2. Using AJAX with stringify to append the service account JSON key file with the request which is sent to the same URL above.

   ```
   checkStatus: function() {
   if (this.get('stop') || !this.getOperationUrl()) {
     return;
   }
   $.ajax({
      url: '/getOperation',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        operation_url: this.getOperationUrl(),
        key: this.config_model.get('key'),
      }),
      cache: false,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {
     const result = response.response;
     if (!response.success || !result) {
       console.log(response);
       this.set('response', response);
     } else {
       if (result.done) {
         this.set('response', response);
       } else {
         setTimeout(function() {
           this.checkStatus();
         }.bind(this), 5 * 1000);
       }
     }
   }.bind(this));
   ```